# Pjax causes jquery widgets not working

Tags: yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker, pjax

Datepicker not working with Pjax - is it normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? I've found some solution [on github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui/issues/9) but it's not working for me. Any suggestions / fixes how to solve this problem?

Comment: You will have to elaborate, I suggest providing a code example of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

This is just because your datepicker is not initialized after loading the new content through pjax. You need to initialize the datepicker every time the pjax loading completes.

`$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
    $('#filter-input-name').datepicker();
});`